# Stuck on UIImageView when back from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, background-process

I was looking for a solution not to capture screenshots in cache when entering a background. I found that I can do that by calling `UIImageView` in `AppDelegate` and capture not my screen but custom image.

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

      UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];

      imageView.tag = 101;    
      imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

      [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:imageView];   
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {

UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject viewWithTag:101];   
[imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```

My app logs out the user after some time, shows an error that user have been logged out and returns to the main view. But now when app logs out in background it doesn't remove that `UIImageView` when back to app. How should I remove that `UIImageView`?

Comment: In the logout method write the same two line of code you have written in applicationWillEnterForeground method

Answer (score 0):

Hold your imageView with strong pointer!

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *imageView;
//...
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {

      self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
      self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

      [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:imageView];   
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [self.imageView removeFromSuperview];
}
```